# which tools i must use to traceback code in openMPI?

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

i m kind newbie to MPI world , i m using openMPI 4, i had some benchmarks results plotted in a graph also, in order to find some explination. i must traceback those benchmarks to be able to give a good explanation ? is there any tools,recommanded, integrated or not to use ? thanks for your help.